# Option value doesnt showup in dropdown - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

I am trying to add new options in a dropdown based on the other dropdown value.
the new added option doesnt appear in the dropdown on my custom webkit browser. 
When I try to debug it the values are present in the dropdown, just it doesnt show up in the front end.

I have attached the code but its working in jsbin :(
When I click the empty dropdown and then click New button value doesnt show up but if I dont click the empty dropdown and click new button directly  values appear normally.

https://jsbin.com/kikicuhabo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to write HTML in lower case, and to close the tags.

If you want to use jQuery I recommend to select elements alway with the "$('')" instead of mixing with the "document. ... "

Since yours it is a custom browser I would try a solution in Vanilla JS.

```js
function AddToCB(p_oCB, p_sText) {
   var oSelect = document.querySelector(p_oCB);
   var iNewLast = oSelect.length;
   var sDisplay = p_sText + (iNewLast + 1);
   var oNewItem = document.createElement('option');
   oNewItem.innerHTML = sDisplay;
   oNewItem.setAttribute('value', sDisplay)
   oSelect.appendChild(oNewItem);
   oSelect.selectedIndex = iNewLast;
   return iNewLast; 
}

 function AddOption() {
  var select = document.querySelector("#cmb");
  var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  AddToCB('#list', text);
}
```

```html
<select name="cmbColor" id="cmb">
  <option>AA</option>
  <option>BB</option>
  <option>CC</option>
</select>

<input type="button" class="float-right" VALUE="New" onClick="AddOption()" >

 <select name="list" id="list">
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is not this. problem is when I click the empty drop down first and then add an option it doesn't appear but if I don't click the empty drop down and directly click add option, the option adds perfectly.

Comment: Ok, what about to delete the empty `option`, check now

Comment: so its not empty, when I debug it the value is there but it doesnt appear it on the front end. its a browser problem

Comment: in which browser are you testing it? For me it works like a charm

Comment: its my custom webkit browser. it works on chrome, firefox and other browsers

Comment: well if you cannot give a valid environment to test, I cannot understand the problem, I posted the answer because when I tested, I had undefined on that element. I would to do everything in vanilla javascript, but I don't know anything about your custom browser